# Gamma function integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, self-learning, gamma-function

How does the derivation of  this integral from the Gamma function is equivalent to (n-1)!?$$\Gamma(n)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\Bigg(\ln\frac1x\Bigg)^{n-1}dx$$

Comment: What if you substitute $y=\ln(1/x)$?

Comment: What is $\Gamma(n)$?

Comment: @Nosrati $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. It is a gamma function.

Comment: Use it's definition.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, $\Gamma(n)=(\frac{y^n}{n})$

Comment: There is nothing to *solve* if you take it as the *definition* of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Definition  of $\Gamma $ function is =$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1} dx$. Nosrati and GEdgar provided the correct answer. For your kind of information, I know the intgration by parts, integration by substitution, integration by trignometric substitution, How to find reduction formulae etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Gamma definition 
$$\Gamma(n)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u^{n-1}\ du$$
with substitution $e^{-u}=x$
$$\Gamma(n)=\displaystyle\int_0^1(\ln\frac1x)^{n-1}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the result only for positive integer $n$.

Integrate by parts to get a reduction formula.
$$
\int_0^1\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-1} =
-\left.\frac{x}{n}\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\;\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}
+\int_0^1\frac{1}{n}\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}
=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}
$$
And do the easy initial case $n=1$
$$
\int_0^1\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^{0}dx = 1.
$$
So by induction,
$$
\int_0^1\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-1} = (n-1)!
$$

**added**
Computation for
$$
\left.\frac{x}{n}\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\;\right|_{x=0}^{x=1} .
$$
For $x=1$, we have $\log(1) = 0$ so
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(\log\frac{1}{1}\right)^n = 0.
$$
(Recall $n \ge 1$.)

For $x=0$, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x}{n}\left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^n = 0
$$
since the $x$ goes to zero much, much faster than the $\log$ goes to $\infty$.